# Windows media player does not let you save?

Tags: video, browser, file-management, media

I opened a video (mpeg) from a web page link in Firefox and it by default opened it in Windows Media Player. There did not appear to be any save button in the player !!!!

Does this mean I have to disable WMP and then redownload the whole video again?

Comment: it is probably in your firefox browser cache folder. What version of OS?

Comment: @Logman it says what browser in the question

Answer (score 0):

Firefox browser cache folder might contain the video, check/search the following folder (Windows 7) for the video:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
```